# Разрабатываю приложение в pyqt5 и мне нужно что бы после окна логина открывалось второе рабочее окно как это сделать?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Разрабатываю приложение в *PyQt5*. Мне нужно чтобы, после окна логина, открывалось главное окно.

Как это сделать?

Код окна логина:

##### WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QMessageBox
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('databaselogin.sqlite')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT
    )""")

db.commit()


class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(347, 290)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("free-icon-compass-5207544.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Login.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Login)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.LoginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.LoginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 201, 23))
        self.LoginButton.setObjectName("LoginButton")
        self.LoginEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LoginEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 181, 20))
        self.LoginEdit.setObjectName("LoginEdit")
        self.PasswordEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.PasswordEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 181, 20))
        self.PasswordEdit.setObjectName("PasswordEdit")
        self.RegisterButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.RegisterButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 220, 201, 23))
        self.RegisterButton.setObjectName("RegisterButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.LoginEdit.raise_()
        self.PasswordEdit.raise_()
        self.LoginButton.raise_()
        self.RegisterButton.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        Login.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Login)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Login.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)
        #Обращение к функции логин
        self.log()

        #Второе окно

        class window2(QDialog):

            def __init__(self):
                super(Screen2,self).__init__()
                loadUI('mainwindow.py',self)
        #Обработка нажатия и передача текста с поля
    def log (self):
        self.LoginButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.message(self.LoginEdit.text(),self.PasswordEdit.text()))
        self.RegisterButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.message2(self.LoginEdit.text(),self.PasswordEdit.text()))
        #Вывод текста

    def message (self,LoginEdit,PasswordEdit):
        user_login = LoginEdit
        user_password = PasswordEdit
        error = QMessageBox()
        sql.execute("SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = ?",(user_login,))
        count = sql.fetchone()
        db.commit()
        if not count:
            #Окно ошибки
            print('Нажми регистрация, что бы зарегестрироваться')
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle('error')
            error.setText('Нажми регистрация, что бы зарегестрироваться')
            error.exec_()
        else:#Открытие главного окна

            def openwindow(self):

                self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
                self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
                self.ui.setupUI(self,window)
                self.window.show()

    def message2 (self,LoginEdit,PasswordEdit):
        user_login = LoginEdit
        user_password = PasswordEdit
        sql.execute("SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = ?",(user_login,))
        if sql.fetchone() is None:
            sql.execute("INSERT INTO user (login,password) VALUES (?,?)" , (user_login,user_password,))
            print('Регистрация успешна')
            db.commit()
        else:
            print('Login are register already')
            db.commit()

    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.LoginButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.RegisterButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Register"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Login", "Password"))


    #Обработка нажатия и передача текста с поля

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Login = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Login()
    ui.setupUi(Login)
    Login.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Это форма второго окна, которое должно открываться:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1135, 745)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 160, 392, 236))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1135, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Я немного поправил ваш код, попробуйте. Если вам что-то не понятно - спросите.

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1135, 745)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 160, 392, 236))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1135, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            

db = sqlite3.connect('databaselogin.db')                        # + .db
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
        login TEXT,
        password TEXT
        )""")
db.commit()

class Ui_Login(object):
    def setupUi(self, Login):
        Login.setObjectName("Login")
        Login.resize(347, 290)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("free-icon-compass-5207544.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Login.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Login)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.LoginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.LoginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 190, 201, 23))
        self.LoginButton.setObjectName("LoginButton")
        self.LoginEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LoginEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 181, 20))
        self.LoginEdit.setObjectName("LoginEdit")
        self.PasswordEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.PasswordEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 181, 20))
        self.PasswordEdit.setObjectName("PasswordEdit")
        self.RegisterButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.RegisterButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 220, 201, 23))
        self.RegisterButton.setObjectName("RegisterButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 71, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.LoginEdit.raise_()
        self.PasswordEdit.raise_()
        self.LoginButton.raise_()
        self.RegisterButton.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_2.raise_()
        Login.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Login)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Login.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Login)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)

    def retranslateUi(self, Login):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Login.setWindowTitle(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.LoginButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.RegisterButton.setText(_translate("Login", "Register"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Login", "Login"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Login", "Password"))


class Window2(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                                     # +++
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
# ?     loadUI('mainwindow.py',self)
        self.setupUi(self)
                    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Login):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
            
        self.setupUi(self)
            
        self.LoginButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.message(self.LoginEdit.text(), self.PasswordEdit.text()))
        self.RegisterButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.message2(self.LoginEdit.text(), self.PasswordEdit.text()))

    def message(self, loginEdit, passwordEdit):
        user_login = loginEdit
        user_password = passwordEdit
        if not user_login or not user_password:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'error',
                'Что-то пошло не так. Проверьте логин и пароль'
            )
            return
            
        error = QMessageBox()
        sql.execute(
            "SELECT login FROM user WHERE login=? AND password=?",
            (user_login, user_password))
        count = sql.fetchone()
        db.commit()
            
        if not count:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle('error')
            error.setText('Что-то пошло не так. \n'
                'Проверьте логин и пароль или   \n'
                'нажми регистрация, что бы зарегестрироваться.')
            error.exec_()
        else:                                          # Открытие главного окна
            self.window2 = Window2()                   # +++
            self.window2.show()
            self.hide()

    def message2 (self, loginEdit, passwordEdit):
        user_login = loginEdit
        user_password = passwordEdit
        if not user_login or not user_password:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'error',
                'Что-то пошло не так. Проверьте логин и пароль'
            )
            return
            
        sql.execute("SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = ?",(user_login,))
            
        if sql.fetchone() is None:
            sql.execute(
                "INSERT INTO user (login, password) VALUES (?,?)", 
                (user_login, user_password,)
            )
            print('Регистрация успешна')
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Успех',
                'Вы успешно зарегистрировались. \n'
                'Попробуйте залогиниться. Удачи Вам.'
            )
        else:
            print('Login are register already')
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'error',
                'Что-то пошло не так. \n'
                'Такой логин уже существует.'
                'Попробуйте залогиниться.'
            )
            return
                
        db.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да,все вышло, спасибо большое вам!